# What is the name of the bond between oxygen atoms and Na+ ions when NaCl dissolves in water?

Tags: bond, aqueous-solution, salt

When NaCl (sodium chloride, table salt) dissolves in water, the NaCl molecules break apart. The hydrogen atoms form [hydrogen bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond) (I think?) with the Cl- ions. What is the name of the bond between the oxygen atoms and the Na+ ions?

Comment: There is no molecules in solid sodium chloride. There is a series of alternating $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions alined on the three axes Ox, Oy and Oz. When dissolved in water, these ions are simply separated without any molecular breaking.

Comment: *Hydrogen bonding* is mainly used for polar covalent bonds and not for free ions.

Comment: Both the sodium cation and chloride anion will be surrounded by polar water molecules forming a "coordination sphere." However such + and - groups can be attracted to one another in concentrated solutions and form an *ion pair*. Ion pairing is one reason that activities differ from concentrations.